# SUMIF with formula based cells in row

Tags: google-sheets

I'm attempting to create the sum (count) of all columns that contain the word "Correct".

The SUMIF I'm using in K2 is
=sumif(C2:L2,"Correct",C2:L2)

The cells in C2:L2 are formatted as such:
=if(Sheet1!K4=Sheet1!K2,"Correct","Incorrect")

So in cell K2, my goal is to count each column that is marked "Correct" as 1 and sum the count.

Could anyone help with what I'm doing wrong? Currently, my K2 SUMIF returns a 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just need COUNTIF in this situation (but of course you can't invoke that formula within the referenced range, as your question implies).

`=COUNTIF(C2:L2;"Correct")`

Comment: Adam, thank you - worked PERFECTLY.  That just goes to show you can't make a function work the wrong way ;)